# What happens when MaxKeepAliveRequests limit is exceeded?

Tags: apache

If a user hits the MaxKeepAliveRequests limit, what happens?

Does the user get an error or does it just create a new connection?

Answer (score 2):

MaxKeepAliveRequests is used in combination with the KeepAlive flag. When the user makes MaxKeepAliveRequests requests the connection will be closed at the end of the response. Apache may also close the connection if the KeepAliveTimeout is reached. The client will get a broken pipe (or connection closed depending on your operating system) if they try to make another request on the socket.

To a certain extend it is up to the client to decide what it does. It could crash or catch the exception and make another request.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is Apache will close the process and create a new process.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a header "connection:close" in the last response.